# Gdi+ DrawImage returns Out of Memory (C++)

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, gdi+, drawimage

I have a problem when I'm trying to draw a bitmap into another one using the "DrawImage" function of GDI+.
My problem only appears when the sizes of the bitmaps are pretty big (in the below code I replaced the size variables by the actual value of a typical non-working case).

The problem is : **DrawImage result is "Out of Memory" (and so nothing is displayed).**

Here is the code (simplified) :

```
Bitmap* pclBitmapDest = new Bitmap(12821, 2400); // Creation and internal status is OK
Graphics* pclGraphicsDest = Graphics::FromImage(pclBitmapDest); // Creation and internal status is OK

Bitmap* pclBitmapSource = new Bitmap(12620, 2400); // Creation and internal status is OK
Graphics* pclGraphicsSource = Graphics::FromImage(pclBitmapSource); // Creation and internal status is OK

// ... Work on pclGraphicsSource to add some shapes into... Everything is OK.

ImageAttributes l_clImageAttributes;
clImageAttributes.SetColorKey(Color::White, Color::White, ColorAdjustTypeBitmap);
Rect stRectangleSource(200, 0, 12620, 2400);

// Add the "Source" bitmap to the "Dest" bitmap
pclGraphicsDest->DrawImage(pclBitmapSource, stRectangleSource, 0, 0, pclBitmapSource->GetWidth(), pclBitmapSource->GetHeight(), UnitPixel, &clImageAttributes); // lastResult=OutOfMemory (3)
```

I know that these images are pretty big, but in this case my program "only" use about 300Mo of RAM which is not that much (I have 8Go...). And I especially don't understand why I would need more memory at this step as both Bitmap are already created, and I just "copy" the data of one in the other one (at least that's only what I want to do!).

I'm working with C++ MFC under Visual Studio 2013, and my PC is a 64bit with 8Go of RAM (Windows 10).

Thanks a lot for your answer,
Cheers,
Alex.

Comment: Check `GetLastStatus` method after creating `pclBitmapDest and pclBitmapSource` as per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534175(v=vs.85).aspx).  Also try ensuring the rectangle `stRectangleSource` is well within destination image (although not sure about this point).

Comment: I actually already call `GetLastStatus` for both bitmaps and the result is Ok. I'm also sur that the rectangle `stRectangleSource` is well within destination image (but I'm almost sur that this case is handled).